# I need some assistance with using a specific php function within an HTML webpage

Tags: php, html, pdo, sqlite

I am currently working on a PHP and SQLite application. It does have HTML for the webpages being created. I am currently using PDO to connect the database to my online server. When I get to the webpage that allows me to type in what I am searching for then it will display what I have found in the echo statements below. I want to be able to have just the item name, that acts as a hyperlink; when it is clicked on it will go to another webpage (I believe) that will display the item's name, amount, and a short description. Is there a way to use PHP for this action or should I go with the HTML  tagging?

```
if($_POST && isset($_POST['search'])) {

echo "<br>\n";
$query = $mysql->prepare('SELECT * FROM Items WHERE Name = :partname');
$subst = array ('partname' => $_POST['search']);
$query->execute($subst);

echo "<TABLE>";
echo "<tr>";
echo "<td>Name</td>";
echo "<td>Amount</td>";
echo "<td>Detail</td>";
echo "</tr>";

while ($row = $query->fetch()) {
    //print_r($row);
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>$row[Name]</td>";
    echo "<td>$row[Amount]</td>";
    echo "<td>$row[Detail]</td>";       
    echo "</tr>";
}
echo "</TABLE>";

} else  echo "Item searched for was not found.";
```

Comment: how do you want the link?

Comment: @PHPglue After I have fixed the hyperlinking issue, right now my code goes to an HTML page and it has buttons where I can work with items that are in my database. The buttons are adding a new amount into the database, and deleting the item displayed from the database. I am having issues trying to take information over from my search.php such as the item that was searched its name, amount and description to another file. I need it to show up on another page so I can work with the buttons that I have created for that page.

Comment: You need to show us code that points to your issues. We're not mind readers. Everything should be AJAX anyways.

Comment: @PHPglue Thank you for responding to my question. I have successfully figured out the solution for my problem I needed to use the get function to pass data from one page to another. P.S. Sorry it took so long to respond I have been busy with many things since Christmas break.

Answer (score 0):

from what i understand

```
    if($_POST && isset($_POST['search'])) {

    echo "<br>\n";
    $query = $mysql->prepare('SELECT * FROM Items WHERE Name = :partname');
    $subst = array ('partname' => $_POST['search']);
    $query->execute($subst);

    echo "<TABLE>";
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>Name</td>";
    echo "</tr>";

    while ($row = $query->fetch()) {
        //print_r($row);
        $name = $row['Name'];
        echo "<tr>";
        echo "<td><a href='details.php?name={$name}'>{$name}</a></td>";   
        echo "</tr>";
    }
    echo "</TABLE>";

    } else  echo "Item searched for was not found.";
```

Answer (score 0):

To use Associative Arrays within double quotes, you need to use curly braces:

```
echo "<td>{$row['Name']}</td><td>{$row['Amount']}</td><td>{$row['Detail']}</td>";
```

Comment: Colon is unneeded, PHP auto-adds if not present.

Comment: This is similar to what I used for my code I used:  echo "<td><a href=$link" . ">" . $row['Name'] . "</a></td>";

Comment: @phpglue After I have fixed the hyperlinking issue, right now my code goes to an HTML page and it has buttons where I can work with items that are in my database. The buttons are adding a new amount into the database, and deleting the item displayed from the database. I am having issues trying to take information over from my search.php such as the item's name, amount and description. I am wanting to take it over to another file and work with the buttons that I have created to edit the data in my database.